# Responsiveness is completely broken + unidentifiable margin across whole body?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

https://github.com/donnieberry97/portfolio

https://donnieberry97.github.io/portfolio/

I have linked my github and my website. I am trying to build my portfolio website so it is still very early stages.

I have built the majority of the desktop view and I am trying to build the mobile site now. However, when I shrink the site, the site completely breaks on mobile.

There seems to be a global margin for the whole page on the right side when in mobile view and I cannot figure out what it is, could anybody help out?

Comment: You might want to make your question more precise for it not to be downvoted. As the response said the issue come from the email font being too big. I suggest editing the question around this specific email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further down the page you have this email address written in a very large font-size:

```
<a class="email" href="mailto:donniejrberry@gmail.com">donniejrberry@gmail.com</a>
```

Since the mail address contains no spaces, it's kept in *one* line, but since you use a quite large font-size for it, that's wider than the `body`! This forces your whole page to be as wide as the mail address and therefore generates a horizontal scrollbar since that's wider than the viewport.

Solution: Use a smaller `font-size` for that line in the mobile version.

And for the rest of the not-so-good looking stuff, also use media queries and smaller font-sizes in it for many of the elements.